# Difference between the cat command with parenthesis

Tags: perl

whats the difference between  the 2 below catfile command in perl

```
my $test = File::Spec->catfile(A, B,C);
```

and

```
my $test = File::Spec->catfile((A, B), C);
```

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Well, the second one includes "C", and the first one does not.</strike> [*Update:* the question has now been updated and they both contain "C".]

Other than that, they're the same. Arguments to method calls (and subroutine calls in general) are flattened into a single list. The parentheses don't do anything.

(Aside: technically the lists `(A, B, C)` and `((A, B), C)` build different optrees, but the difference occurs at a very low level, and unless it pulled some pretty extensive stunts poking around in the Perl internals, `catfile` would be unable to tell the difference between the two lists.)

In certain circumstances parentheses like this, though they don't do anything, might aid clarity - in this case the author might have added them to make it clear that "A" and "B" are conceptually different arguments than "C". If you're familiar with the API of File::Spec, then you'll know that the last argument to `catfile` is a filename, while the others are directory names. So that might be the reason they've been visually separated using parentheses.

Comment: lets assume I  if B is optional then how shld i do it?

Comment: Generally speaking, if an argument is optional and you don't want to provide it, you just omit it from the list. `foo($x, $y)` versus `foo($x)`.

Comment: I am trying to solve problem in which  i want to find C in some linux box its A/C in some its A/B/C so B is optional .How to cat them?

Comment: I think what you probably want to do is create a list of candidate file names, use `grep` to search through that list, and use one of the file test operators (like `-f` which tests that a file exists, and is *actually a file* rather than a directory), to find the candidate that you want. [Here is an example](https://gist.github.com/tobyink/8820443).